# How to input commands c++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying implement commands in a c++ console app
The app has a command prompt , basically does nothing until you type a specific command , now the problem is I can't find an efficient way to do this, the only solution I can think of is implementing thousands of if else statements which are not exactly efficient, also switch statements don't work on strings,
The commands are separate functions with different arguments and all commands are  preprocessor definitions,

I tried implementing if else statements but they were silly

one *other* way i also could think of was using a scripting language and implementing my own functions, for example i could use chaiscript and implement my own function called 'new' which takes two parameters (first what type of file and second the name of the file) and i could give it the command line inputs instead of a script file, this approach could save me from creating my own scripting language or command line interface(whatever it is called)

Comment: `std::string cmd;` `std::getline(std::cin, cmd);` `if(cmd == "secret") { /* do stuff */ }` or use a `std::unordered_map` to map from your commands to whatever function you want ot execute for each command

Comment: You are reading input from user. `if` chain is hardly going to be noticeable. Don't bother with performance until it is actually not meeting requirements.

Comment: Watch the tags. The approaches in C are quite different from C++. Depending on the size of the protocol a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function>` could be what you are looking for.

Comment: Side note: It's often a good idea to show even the silly attempts. That attempt A) might not be all that silly and B) could be the only thing separating your question from being dismissed as zero-effort homework crowd sourcing.

Comment: This question is unanswerable within the guidelines of Stack Overflow, as you have not provided a code example that represents what you're trying to achieve.  As a result, potential solutions will be generic and not tailored to your needs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a std::map of string => std::function

Like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
typedef std::function<void(const std::string &)> CmdFunc;
void cmda(const std::string &line) {
    std::cout << "cmda " << line << "\n";
}
void cmdb(const std::string& line) {
    std::cout << "cmdb " << line << "\n";
}

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, CmdFunc > cmds;
    cmds["a"] = cmda;
    cmds["b"] = cmdb;
    //...
    while (true) {

        std::string cmdLine;
        std::getline(std::cin, cmdLine);
        std::string token = cmdLine.substr(0, cmdLine.find(" "));
        auto find = cmds.find(token);
        if (find != cmds.end())
            (find->second)(cmdLine);
        else
            std::cout << "unknown command\n";

    }
}
```

output

```
a froot
cmda a froot
b wang
cmdb b wang
c
unknown command
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for thanks